# Cannot toggle window menubar visibility in NW.js

Tags: javascript, nw.js

I want to be able to make the menubar appear/disappear at certain times.

According to NW.js [doccumentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/), setting window's menu property to null completely removes the menubar. However, the menubar persists when I use the following script:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var your_menu = new gui.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });
gui.Window.get().menu = your_menu;
gui.Window.get().menu = null;
```

I am missing something? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json` file you may set these options and some more. Among these is the one you want. Just copy the desired options, you don't need all, this is just an example list of what you may want.

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "description": "demo app of node-webkit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "keywords": [ "demo", "node-webkit" ],
  "window": {
    "title": "node-webkit demo",
    "icon": "link.png",
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500,
    "position": "mouse",
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200,
    "max_width": 800,
    "max_height": 600
  },
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
  }
}
```

The one you are interested in is:

```
"toolbar": false,
```

nested inside the `"window": {` option.

Comment: Thanks, but I what I'm trying to do is to toggle the menubar visibility at certain times, not disable it forever. I guess I wasn't clear enough, I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

If you add this script block to your `index.html`, it will show a menubar with a single menu that has a `Hide` command.

Clicking `Hide` toggles the menubar visibility as you are trying to do.

```
<script>

  addHideableMenu();

  function addHideableMenu(){
    let win = nw.Window.get();
    let mnu = new nw.Menu({ type: 'menubar' });
    let submenu = new nw.Menu();
    submenu.append(new nw.MenuItem( { label: 'Hide', click: function() { win.menu = null; }}));
    mnu.append(new nw.MenuItem({ label: 'Menu', submenu: submenu }));
    win.menu = mnu;
  }
  
</script>
```